# Canvas image with edit option

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas, html2canvas

I am going to create the canvas image then i am  going to right a text over that canvas. If i did like this means text control is not appearing properly and initially created canvas image is overlapping with new one. My purpose is for custome t shirt editing with background color setfings, editing placing image .

Comment: please share code what you have tried so far

Comment: Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.

Comment: without seeing code, it will be difficult to fix the error

Comment: For security reasons, trying to use an image from a different domain in a canvas causes problems (i.e. a tainted canvas). Try putting the image in the same folder with the canvas.